# Interacting with Home Device Without Assistant or Sender App

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-cast, google-home

**What SDK/API is intended for interacting with Home devices without Assistant?**

I'm very new to developing for google home/assistant, and I fall within the hobbyist category. I do have experience with node, and I've been exploring the possibility of adding a functionality to the google home devices in my house. I have been reviewing docs on dialogflow, and actions on google, but I'm having trouble determining what method/service in Google's sprawling developer ecosystem would be correct for a project like this (if any).

The idea is that I could click a button on a webpage served in node, which then plays a hosted sound file on all google home devices in my house. While this sounds similar to Cast SDK to me, I'm intending to play a hosted sound like a buzzer or beep on home devices, just one time. All the documentation I'm seeing for cast developing indicates it is not designed for cases like this, especially since phones/mobile devices (i.e. sender apps) don't factor into this concept at all. In my scenario, I'm also picturing being able to play the sound on all home devices, interrupting regardless of what is currently streaming on those devices through cast playback.

This leads me to think this is normally handled through dialogflow with a webhook, but there are a few things I'm confused about: the sound playback *would not* be triggered via conversation with Assistant. From the docs I've been trying to make sense of, it looks like a webhook trigger or [query request](https://dialogflow.com/docs/events#invoking_an_event_via_query_request) might make sense here, however webhooks still appear to be designed to carry user queries to Assistant to my server and then respond.

**Is there an official SDK or API specifically designed for use cases like this - interacting with a Home Device (sound playback in this case) without using the Assistant or a Chrome/Android/iOS sender app?**

INTENDED FUNCTIONALITY:

[image: intended functionality:]

Comment: No, the type of use case you mention is not available as an API

Comment: @NickFelker that's too bad - thanks for your response.